# AudioNode.disconnect() followed by .connect() not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api, microphone

I've built a demo of a voice-assistant that takes microphone data, passes it to an analyzer, then uses `.getByteFrequencyData()` to show visuals. It works as follows:

1. Press mic button to connect to microphone input
2. Release mic button disconnects microphone stream, and plays MP3 of response.
3. When MP3 ends: return to standby, and wait for new button press to start step 1. again.

Live version here: https://dyadstudios.com/playground/daysi/

The way I've achieved this is as follows:

```js
var audioContext = (window.AudioContext) ? new AudioContext() : new window["webkitAudioContext"]();
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = Math.pow(2, 9);  // 512
var sourceMic = undefined;  // Microphone stream source
var sourceMp3 = undefined;  // MP3 buffer source

// Browser requests mic access
window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then((stream) => {
    sourceMic = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
})

// 1. Mic button pressed, start listening
listen() {
    audioContext.resume();

    // Connect mic to analyser
    if (sourceMic) {
        sourceMic.connect(analyser);
    }
}

// 2. Disconnect mic, play mp3
answer(mp3AudioBuffer) {
    if (sourceMic) {
        // Disconnect mic to prevent audio feedback
        sourceMic.disconnect();
    }

    // Play mp3
    sourceMp3 = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    sourceMp3.onended = mp3StreamEnded;
    sourceMp3.buffer = mp3AudioBuffer;
    sourceMp3.connect(analyser);
    sourceMp3.start(0);

    // Connect to speakers to hear MP3
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
}

// 3. MP3 has ended
mp3StreamEnded() {
    sourceMp3.disconnect();

    // Disconnect speakers (prevents mic feedback)
    analyser.disconnect();
}
```

It works perfectly well on Firefox and Chrome, but OSX Safari 12.1 only gets microphone data the first time I press the button. Whenever I press the mic button on a second pass, the analyzer no longer gets microphone data, but MP3 data still works. It seems like connecting, disconnecting, and re-connecting the mic's AudioNode to the analyzer breaks it somehow. I checked and Safari supports [`AudioNode.connect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/connect#Browser_compatibility) as well as [`AudioNode.disconnect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/disconnect#Browser_compatibility). I know Safari's WebAudio implementation is a bit outdated, is there a workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a bug in Safari which causes it to drop the signal if a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode is disconnected for some time. You can avoid this by just not disconnecting it as long as you might need it again. You can use a GainNode instead to mute the signal.

You could do this by introducing a new variable to control the volume.

```
const sourceMicVolume = audioContext.createGain();

sourceMicVolume.gain.value = 0;
```

Then you need to connect everything right away when you instantiate the `sourceMic`.

```
sourceMic = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

sourceMic.connect(sourceMicVolume);
sourceMicVolume.connect(analyser);
```

Inside your event handlers you would then only set the volume of the gain instead of (dis)connecting the nodes. Inside the `listen()` function that would look like this:

```
if (sourceMic) {
    sourceMicVolume.gain.value = 1;
}
```

And inside the `answer()` function it would look like this:

```
if (sourceMic) {
    sourceMicVolume.gain.value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this WebKit bug has already been reported? I'd be happy to do so if it hasn't, but I'm not very up-to-date in the WebAudio community.

Comment: Darn, this fix worked on Safari for MacOS, but Safari on iOS plays the MP3s at a fraction of their original volume when microphone access is granted, even though the MP3's buffersource is never connected to the gain node. However, when mic access is denied, the MP3s play at their normal volume. I wonder if they did this is on purpose to try to prevent feedback?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know if this has been reported yet. I stopped reporting bugs in Safari to Apple as I had the feeling that they are not taking it seriously anyway. But that was some time ago and hopefully that has changed now. I would appreciate if you could give it a try.

Comment: I once had the problem with the lowered volume as well. I managed to avoid it by not using any <audio/> element on the page. But since you don't seem to use any <audio/> element, I don't know what could cause the issue in your case. Unfortunately I don't have a generalized solution for that.

Comment: When you use getUserMedia on mobile it switches the device from speaker mode, this is why there is a seeming volume change. It does seem a bit flakey in Safari and unfortunately they don’t let you access the output devices to route the audio back to speaker.